# How can I read the content of a cell in Google Sheets and use it to set values in other cells?

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I am working on a calculations form with several columns so multiple users can use it concurrently.

The layout is 1 column for the number data and the next is for setting varying weights to apply for each entry.  That's all working.

What I'm looking to do is setup a pull-down menu with the various data columns listed where a user can select the column they were working in and hit the clear button to clear their entries.

I also want to setup a pull-down menu with the various weight columns listed where a user can select the column they customized weighting in and reset it.

I have created scripts to manually do this but I want to be able to substitute the selected column rather than have 26 different scripts and buttons.

Here are the manual scripts that address the data column Z and the weight column AA:

```
function resetFormCDataColumn() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('z1:z4').setValue('');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('z8:z9').setValue('');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('z12:z13').setValue('');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('z16:z17').setValue('');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('z20:z21').setValue('');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('z24:z25').setValue('');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('z29:z30').setValue('');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('z36:z37').setValue('');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('z40:z41').setValue('');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('z45:z48').setValue('');
}

function resetFormCWeights() {
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA3').setValue('1');
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA6').setValue('1');
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA7').setValue('1');
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA8').setValue('1');
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA11').setValue('1');
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA12').setValue('1');
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA15').setValue('1');
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA16').setValue('1');
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA19').setValue('1');
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA20').setValue('1');
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA23').setValue('1');
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA24').setValue('1');
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA27').setValue('1');
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA29').setValue('1');
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA32').setValue('1');
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA33').setValue('1');
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA35').setValue('1');
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA36').setValue('1');
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA39').setValue('1');
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA40').setValue('1');
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA43').setValue('1');
}
```

I want to replace the z ad aa entries based on the select pull-down option when they click the button (see image for example).

How do I do this?

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHSvH.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question to remove unnecessary stuff.